# Define property like margin in user control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to define a property in user control which is similar margin property, how can i define it ? so that it will show All,Left,top,right,bottom when expanded in designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margin property is defined as a struct:

```
public struct Padding
{
    public int All { get; set; };
    public int Bottom { get; set; }
    public int Left { get; set; }
    public int Right { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

So you can define your property as `Padding` or like a custom struct looking like this one.